# Can someone show me if my steps are wrong in solving $\int \frac{\sqrt{1+\ln x}}{x \ln x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I just need to know if this method of solving this integral
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{1+\ln x}}{x \ln x} dx
$$ is correct or not and if not where am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: and that makes it all wrong doesnt it

Comment: I think it is t^2 @OfirSchnabel

Comment: The denominator of the original integrand is $x\ln(x)$.  Hint:  Try using the substitution $u = x\ln(x)$.

Comment: 100 % Correct, dont forget lastly to substitute again to get the final result in  terms of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

You may just perform the change of variable 
\begin{equation*}
v=\sqrt{1+\ln x},\quad \ln x=v^2-1,\quad  x=e^{v^2-1}, \quad dx=2ve^{v^2-1}dv,\quad \frac{dx}x =2v\:dv
\end{equation*}
to get
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt{1+\ln x}}{x \ln x} dx&=\int \frac{v}{v^2-1} 2v\:dv\\\\
&=2\int \frac{v^2}{v^2-1}dv\\\\
&=2\int dv+2\int  \frac{1}{v^2-1}dv\\\\
&=2v+\log \left|\frac{1-v}{1+v}\right|+C\\\\
&=2\sqrt{1+\ln x}+ \log\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+\ln x}-1}{\sqrt{1+\ln x}+1}\right|+C.
\end{align}
$$ **Thus what you did is correct.**

Comment: I think the final answer is missing a  $log$ :)

Comment: Typo corrected. Thank you!

Comment: Find it in order..